# Hide scroll bar even when the cursor hovers the div

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have a div with a text scrolled up and down with 2 simple buttons & JS.
I wish to totally disable the scroll bars so they will never appear on the screen, even if the crosser is above them.

How do i approach this problem?

Thank Shani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to the css rule for that div.